# Different techniques to implement Dependency Injection

Tags: .net, dependency-injection

Can anyone please tell me the different approaches to implement Dependency Injection like 
1. Unity framework
2. Ninject
3. Autofac
Are there any other techniques to implement DI. If yes what are they?

Comment: This is too broad. Read the "getting started" section of each projects' help section and return here with an actual question. To find more projects, type ".net dependency injection" in your favourite web search engine. And please [keep it to one question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19093357/dependency-injection-using-autofac-with-mvc4-web-api) on the same subject.

Comment: I dont need deep explanation, I just need the names only.

Comment: There are other .NET implementations of the Dependency Injection/Inversion of Control design pattern.  Check out [Martin Fowler's post](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) if you want to learn more about the technique. It discusses a variety of approaches.

Comment: [Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43296/Introduction-to-Munq-IOC-Container-for-ASP-NET)

Answer (score 2):

Unity, Ninject, etc are DI containers and not techniques for implementing dependency injection.  Although some containers do favor certain techniques.

The general ways of implementing dependency injection are constructor, setter, and interface injection as described by Martin Fowler.

[Forms of Dependency Injection](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#FormsOfDependencyInjection)

Comment: For instance, Unity favors the use of interception through dynamic proxies, while Simple Injector favors the use of decorators.